# How to run an append query in ms access vba as part of a transaction

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling, transactions, rollback

I'm very new to programming and have been building my company's inventory database on MS Access 2016. I've been able to get by just fine with macros so far, but I'm trying to run a transaction made of append and delete queries and am struggling with the vba code.

I figured out how to run a transaction where the queries fail on error. However, the append query I'm trying to include in the transaction is drawing values from a blank form, and as far as I can figure out, that means I need to define the query parameters in the code.

So this is the code where the transaction and error handling works:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim ws As DAO.Workspace, db As DAO.Database
Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = ws.Databases(0)
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs

On Error GoTo ErrTrap

ws.BeginTrans
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
db.Execute "TESTQRY1", dbFailOnError
db.Execute "TEST2QRY", dbFailOnError
db.Execute "TESTQRY3", dbFailOnError

ws.CommitTrans

MsgBox ("You have successfully updated the data")
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    ws.Rollback
    MsgBox "Rollback needed because:" & vbCr & Err.Description

End Sub
```

And this is the code that works for actually running the query, but which doesn't have the error handling or transaction working:

```
Private Sub Add_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qry As DAO.QueryDef
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace

Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = ws.Databases(0)
Set qry = db.QueryDefs("APPENDQRY")

qry.Parameters(0) = Forms!LotNumberFrm!txtLotNumber
qry.Parameters(1) = Forms!LotNumberFrm!txtFWNumber
qry.Parameters(2) = Forms!LotNumberFrm!txtExpDate
qry.Parameters(3) = Forms!LotNumberFrm!chkActive

qry.Execute

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

So basically my issue is that I need to do both of these things at the same time - run the query as part of a transaction with error handling AND define the query parameters in the code.

I've tried to slice and splice these two bits of code together a bunch of different ways without success. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why you were unable to integrate the code from your first section into your second question, but I'll do it for you.

```vb
Private Sub Add_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qry As DAO.QueryDef
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = ws.Databases(0)
Set qry = db.QueryDefs("APPENDQRY")

qry.Parameters(0) = Forms!LotNumberFrm!txtLotNumber
qry.Parameters(1) = Forms!LotNumberFrm!txtFWNumber
qry.Parameters(2) = Forms!LotNumberFrm!txtExpDate
qry.Parameters(3) = Forms!LotNumberFrm!chkActive

On Error GoTo ErrTrap
ws.BeginTrans
qry.Execute
ws.CommitTrans
Exit Sub
ErrTrap:
    ws.Rollback
    MsgBox "Rollback needed because:" & vbCr & Err.Description
End Sub
```

An alternative way to execute a single query transactionally is the following:

```
qry.Execute dbFailOnError
```

This rolls back the query on an error. No need for any workspace stuff.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for the answer. I put this code in my form and then tested it out by entering data that should have raised an error due to validation rules in the destination table. However, when I checked the table after running the code, a new record had been appended (the field with incorrectly formatted data was blank, but all the other fields were there). Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Nevermind! I just had to add dbFailOnError after the qry.Execute in the code you sent and it works like a charm. Thanks so much!