# Getting the number of affected records by an action query in VBA

Tags: vba, variables, ms-access, insert, store

I'm wondering if it is possible to pick a variable which is being used by MS Access when inserting a specific amount of new data rows to a table which happens during a VBA runtime.

**Screenshot of the MS Access Notification (in German):**

[image: Screenshot of the MS Access Notification (in German)]

MS Access notifies me here in that case that in the middle of a running VBA script 2327 new data rows are being added to the table. I'm not a programmer but I feel that this variable must be stored somewhere (at least temporary).

Does anyone has an idea how to pick/access this number from the window when it  appears and then store it into an VBA Integer for further use in the future?

**Update:**

Basically, I have a main database which has to be updated every day by an import file.

In the first step there is a check for already existing datasets which will therefore only updated by an UPDATE-Query.

```
UPDATE ReiseMaster
INNER JOIN Update_Import
ON(ReiseMaster.Col1 = Update_Import.Col1)
   SET ReiseMaster.Col2  = Update_Import.Col2,
       ReiseMaster.Col3  = Update_Import.Col3;
```

Then, in the second step new datasets which are not existing in the main database will be inserted into it will all the information they contain. This is the SQL-Query which is responsible for appending new data rows during the VBA procedure:

```
INSERT INTO ReiseMaster ([Col1],[Col2],[Col3])
SELECT [Col1],[Col2],[Col3] FROM Update_Import 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ReiseMaster
  WHERE Update_Import.[Col1] = ReiseMaster.[Col1]);
```

I am struggling with identifying the amount of new datasets after the procedure, which is in fact already somehow determined by MS Access itself (see Pop-Up). So my idea was to just use the number which is already determined by MS Access.

All SQL-Queries are stored in a string and run by the "DoCmd.RunSQL" command.

Comment: I am inclined to think it cannot be accessed.

Comment: Probably not, but impossible for us to say based on the information provided. If code is doing something to append records then it's more likely to be able to pull the information from the code's actions. But since you don't provide a [mcve] there's no way to know...

Comment: If you're inserting data using `DoCmd` statements, these prompts get auto-generated, and there's no way to pull data from them. Instead, you could rewrite the code to make use of DAO, and then you can get the number of records affected yourself, show a prompt, and retain the information.

Comment: I've updated my post above to meet the expectations by adding the SQL-Queries and the hint that they will be run by DoCmd.RunSQL statements. Thanks for the comments until now, so there is basically no possibility to grab that value directly, instead, I have to calculate the amount by myself using DAO, correct?

Comment: @Xalion Well, you have to stop executing the query through DoCmd, and use DAO to execute it. Please specify if you want a prompt (like the queries are showing currently) to show up, then I can provide an answer that provides the intended behavior (a prompt is a bit of extra work). Please also consider adjusting the title of your question to something like _how can I get the number of records affected by an action query in VBA_ so it's easier to find for future visitors

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I would very much appreciate a bit help from your side! A prompt is not necessary, I'm already very grateful for every little help. As long as I can have a variable which stores the number of affected rows during the runtime of the code, it would be perfectly fine. I'm also very curious to learn from your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using DAO, it's really easy to get the number of records affected after executing a query.

You can just use the `Database.RecordsAffected` property:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb 'Required, don't use CurrentDb.Execute else this won't work
Dim strSQL as String
strSQL =  "UPDATE ReiseMaster INNER JOIN Update_Import" 'and the rest of your query
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError  'Execute the query using Database.Execute
Dim recordsAffected As Long
recordsAffected = db.RecordsAffected 'Get the number of records affected
```

However, this won't allow you to see it before committing the query. To see it and display a prompt, you can use transactions (short sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46851714/7296893)), and rollback the transaction if the user doesn't choose to commit.

Comment: Wow, there is actually a "RecordAffected"-attribute! This is indeed very helpful. I'll take a look into the short sample in case I want to create a prompt for the user, thanks for the hint and help!